# "Restore" registry entries after system rebuild

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-registry

So i just changed my as good as broken hard-drive and installed Windows 8 to a new Primary Drive (SSD 64GB, 6GB/s).

I left my other Hard Drive (Toshiba 500 GB) built into my PC and left the Software on it installed.

Now my new Windows 8 has lost all the shortcuts and registry entries to the programs I installed over the span of more than half a year.

Question:
Is there any way to "restore" / refresh registry entries for already correctly installed Programs after fully new installation of windows?

Would it help to have the old Boot-Partition (except for the Windows folder)?

Comment: I honestly wouldn't recommend it. I don't see any reason to muck-up a perfectly good install with old registry entries and files. My advice would be to just do a fresh re-install all of the old programs. If there's data that can be transitioned over from the old drive, then that's great.

Comment: @joshr well it would be an easy thing to do with some 10-15 programs. But it is a whole different matter when talking about my Gamescollection... in general I would also prefer a reinstallation over messing with the registry, but I don't wanna spend the next week or more with reinstalling all my awesome games...